# JDEdwards XMLInterop

Tags: jdedwards

Wondering if anybody out there has any success in using the JDEdwards XMLInterop functionality. I've been using it for a while (with a simple PInvoke, will post code later). I'm looking to see if there's a better and/or more robust way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As promised, here is the code for integrating with JDEdewards using XML. It's a webservice, but could be used as you see fit.

```
namespace YourNameSpace
```

{

```
/// <summary>
/// This webservice allows you to submit JDE XML CallObject requests via a c# webservice
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://WebSite.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class JdeBFService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private string _strServerName;
    private UInt16 _intServerPort;
    private Int16 _intServerTimeout;

    public JdeBFService()
    {
        // Load JDE ServerName, Port, & Connection Timeout from the Web.config file.
        _strServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JdeServerName"];
        _intServerPort = Convert.ToUInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JdePort"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        _intServerTimeout = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JdeTimeout"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This webmethod allows you to submit an XML formatted jdeRequest document
    /// that will call any Master Business Function referenced in the XML document
    /// and return a response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Xml"> The jdeRequest XML document </param>
    [WebMethod]
    public XmlDocument JdeXmlRequest(XmlDocument xmlInput)
    {
        try
        {
            string outputXml = string.Empty;
            outputXml = NativeMethods.JdeXmlRequest(xmlInput, _strServerName, _intServerPort, _intServerTimeout);

            XmlDocument outputXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            outputXmlDoc.LoadXml(outputXml);
            return outputXmlDoc;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorReporting.SendEmail(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This interop class uses pinvoke to call the JDE C++ dll.  It only has one static function.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This class calls the xmlinterop.dll which can be found in the B9/system/bin32 directory.  
/// Copy the dll to the webservice project's /bin directory before running the project.
/// </remarks>
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("xmlinterop.dll",
        EntryPoint = "_jdeXMLRequest@20",
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        ExactSpelling = false,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr jdeXMLRequest([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder server, UInt16 port, Int32 timeout, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder buf, Int32 length);

    public static string JdeXmlRequest(XmlDocument xmlInput, string strServerName, UInt16 intPort, Int32 intTimeout)
    {
        StringBuilder sbServerName = new StringBuilder(strServerName);
        StringBuilder sbXML = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriter xWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sbXML);
        xmlInput.WriteTo(xWriter);
        xWriter.Close();

        string result = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(jdeXMLRequest(sbServerName, intPort, intTimeout, sbXML, sbXML.Length));

        return result;
    }
}
```

}

You have to send it messages like the following one:

```
<jdeRequest type='callmethod' user='USER' pwd='PWD' environment='ENV'>
  <callMethod name='GetEffectiveAddress' app='JdeWebRequest' runOnError='no'>
    <params>
      <param name='mnAddressNumber'>10000</param>
    </params>
  </callMethod>
</jdeRequest>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. We used to use a COM wrapper which was horrible to maintain.  Now it's pure .NET interop and much cleaner!

Comment: I tried this code and I am getting "Unable to load DLL 'xmlinterop.dll': The specified module could not be found.
xception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" when executing. The dll is in the same directory as the compiled app and in C:\windows\System32\. I've also tried absolute paths...

Answer (score 1):

To anyone trying to do this, there are some dependencies to xmlinterop.dll.

you'll find these files on the fat client here ->c:\E910\system\bin32

this will create a 'thin client'

```
PSThread.dll
icudt32.dll
icui18n.dll
icuuc.dll
jdel.dll
jdeunicode.dll
libeay32.dll
msvcp71.dll
ssleay32.dll
ustdio.dll
xmlinterop.dll
```

Comment: Can anyone tell where exactly can i find this *.dll files?? Do i need to install something to get these dlls?

Comment: you'll find these files on the fat/development  client here ->c:\E910\system\bin32

Answer (score 0):

I changed our JDE web service to use XML Interop after seeing this code, and we haven't had any stability problems since. Previously we were using the COM Connector, which exhibited regular communication failures (possibly a connection pooling issue?) and was a pain to install and configure correctly.

We did have issues when we attempted to use transactions, but if you're doing simple single business function calls this shouldn't be an problem.

**Update:** To elaborate on the transaction issues - if you're attempting to keep a transaction alive over multiple calls, AND the JDE application server is handling a modest number of concurrent calls, the xmlinterop calls start returning an 'XML response failed' message and the DB transaction is left open with no way to commit or rollback. It's possible tweaking the number of kernels might solve this, but personally, I'd always try to complete the transaction in a single call.

Comment: Thanks, that's great additional info Sam!